# I need help making an if statement with many logical operators easier

Tags: java

I've tried searching for it, but I don't really now how to formulate the question correctly...

I have an `if-statement` with many logical operators. How do I do this easier ?

```
If (n == 1 ||n == 2 ||n == 3  ||n == 5 ||n == 9 ||n == 8 ||n == 7 ||n == 551 ||n == 17 ||n == 81 || etc etc)
{ //Stuff
}
```

I'm thinking in pseudo-code I want something like this:

```
List list = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, or 36 }

if n is in list, then {}
```

As you understand, I'm a beginner and I have problems formulating what I need.

Comment: Yes your List approach will work, it's the way to go..

Comment: @smerny No need for a switch if it's a single if statement...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
int[] validOptions = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 17, 81, 551 };

if (Arrays.binarySearch(validOptions, n) >= 0)
{
    // Yup, found it
}
```

Note that I reordered your original check (which had 551 before 17 for example) so that the array is sorted. A binary search will *only* work with sorted data.

I'm only suggesting an array here on the grounds that it's slightly easier to specify, particularly as you're dealing with a primitive type. If you want these to be dynamic, a `List<Integer>` or a `HashSet<Integer>` would be more appropriate.

Note that while it almost certainly doesn't matter while the set is small, it's worth considering the performance characteristics of different lookups:

- `HashSet.contains` - O(1)
- `Arrays.binarySearch` - O(log N)
- `ArrayList.contains` - O(N)

Comment: Come on, everybody just gave hints in the comments, you deliver code!?! That´s evil! :D

Comment: @AleksG, his and the OP's arrays both appears to be sorted. it will be faster this way.

Comment: @AleksG: Which is why I sorted it :) I'll explain that in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, throw everything in an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and then use the [`.contains(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
number.add(...;

if(numbers.contains(n))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 static private Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(
     Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36));
```

then to test:

```
if (set.contains(n))
```

Using a `HashSet` will make it perform pretty well.

Comment: If the collection is re-used, then the HashSet wrapping will definitely perform better.  However, if the list is only searched once, this is quite a bit slower.  The advantage to hashing is to make searching faster, but the construction of the hash table requires sequential scanning of the array.  If you only search it once, then you may as well do a linear search.

Answer (score 1):

Your List approach is correct.  You can do something like this:

```
int[] values = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36 };
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if(values.asList(list).contains(n)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrayinside(n, listofn) {
    var length = listofn.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(listofn[i] == n) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Try this

Comment: This looks like Javascript and though it certainly solves the problem it is not a relevant answer since the OP is asking for advice on Java.